# Kendo UI Grid Chaning dropdown does not update cell due to template

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I am trying to get the selection made from a drop down to show in the cell of a grid but it is not working.

Previously I had the template set to the name of a "condition" e.g. new, used, broken. When a selection was made it would not change unless the grid was reloaded (it saved the change to the database).

Now I have followed a few tutorials but I can't get it to work:

my columns:

```
{
            title: 'Condition',
            field: 'condition',
            width: '120px',
            filterable: {
                ui: gridFunctions.conditionFilterUI.bind(activeGrid)
            },
            editor: gridFunctions.conditionEditor.bind(undefined, ctrlDown),
            template: '#=condition.condition_name#'
        },
```

SQL columns:

```
parts_conditions.id AS condition_id, parts_conditions.condition AS condition_name,
```

Kendo grid model:

```
model: {
            id: 'id',
            fields: {
                condition: {
                    defaultValue: {
                        condition_id: 1,
                        condition_name: 'New'
                    }
                },
            }
  }
```

How can I get this to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

use foreign key dropdown.Refer to category column in the below kendo demo:

[http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom](http://Kendo%20demo)